# Extreme Value Problem: Minimizing vs. Maximizing

Tags: optimization, extreme-value-analysis

**Problem:**
Determine the distance between $(0,0,0)$ and the straight line which we get by intersecting the two planes $x-y+z=1$ and $x+y-z=0$.

Distance between a point and origin: $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ with $g_1=x-y+z-1=0$ and $g_2=x+y-z=0$

I think that $f$ gives us the distance between any point on the straight line of the two planes and the origin. By saying "the distance" we actually mean the shortest (the one orthogonal on the line). So we "minimize" the problem.

We can also take the quadratic of $f$ to make it easier.

So we get the lagrangian function:

$L=x^2+y^2+z^2-\lambda(x-y+z-1)-\mu(x+y-z)$

$\partial_xL=2x-\lambda-\mu=0 \Rightarrow \mu=2x-\lambda$

$\partial_yL=2+\lambda-\mu \Rightarrow \mu=2y+\lambda$

$\partial_zL=2z-\lambda+\mu=0 \Rightarrow \mu=-2z+\lambda$

Using the 2nd and 3th eq. we get $y=-z$

using $g_1, g_2$ we get the system of equations:

x-y+z=1

x+y-z=0

z+y=0

Which is solved by $p=(1/2, -1/4, 1/4)$

The wanted distance is now: $d=f(p)=\sqrt{6}/4$

**Question**

Now, what I don't get is where we actually did the minimizing or asked differently: How would I maximie this problem?

My thoughts: The thing we did above was just getting all extremal values. When minimizing, we'd choose the minimum and when maximizing, we'd choose the maximum. That's correct?

Comment: Maybe you can google definition of Lagrangian. But most probably it should be in your lecture notes or in your course book.

Comment: At first you must compute the intersection line of this two planes, this simplifies the given problem

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The question isn't directly about the problem but more about the terms "minimizing, maximiing". The problem is solved.

Comment: @mathreadler why? If somthings wrong then state it. But the problem was really just a little example. The question is more about the terms of "minimiing, maximizing"

Comment: @xotix : On this site, problems are about the question you ask. Make sure you ask the right question or people are likely to become annoyed. Especially if they find out afterwards that they answered the wrong questions for you.

Comment: @mathreadler It was meant as an example, so my question isn't just a one liner with no context. :) But I might set it up badly, true. Sorry

Comment: It’s kind of a shame that problems involving distances to flats are given as practice in the Lagrange multiplier method as there are usually much simpler ways to solve those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric equation of the line of intersection of the planes is $$ x=1/2, y=-t/2, z=1/2 - t/2$$

The distance from the origin satisfies $$d^2 = 1/4 +t^2/4+(1-t)^2/4 $$

The minimum distance happens at $t=1/2$ and it is $d= \sqrt 6 /4.$

There is no maximum value as the distance grows without bound.

Answer (score 0):

In Calc 3 (or the equivalent) we normally don't do much with the 2nd-derivative test.  The one for two-variable functions, the $$D= f_{xx}f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2$$ thing is about the limit of what most students can handle.  But this is an example of the Hessian.  There is a Hessian for the Lagrangian which is essentially the 2nd-derivative test for max vs. min vs. saddle point.  For your example, the Hessian is the determinant of a $5\times 5$ matrix (because there are 5 variables.)  If you determine whether the Hessian matrix is "positive definite", at the critical point, then you know that the point is a local min.  (Note that the $D$ above is the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix.)

If you look at the wiki page for "Hessian" you'll find more than you want to know.

The short answer to your question is that often we use intuition to decide whether a point is a max or min, rather than mess with the Hessian.